# Weird character encoding issue with python / nautilus scripts combo

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have a nautilus script to copy tunes that I like into a special folder which I sync to my phone and my car.  It fails on paths with funny characters like á in them.  I'm fixing it incrementally with stuff like:

```
temp = temp.replace('%20', ' ')
temp = temp.replace('%5B', '[')
temp = temp.replace('%5D', ']')
```

but I'm getting tired of these bandaid solutions, and I'm sure there is a better way to do this with `str.encode` or `str.decode`.

Does anyone recognise this strange encoding and how I can handle it properly?  The problem is, for example, I have a folder such as

`/media/music/kálmán balogh and the gipsy cimbalom band/aven shavale`

on my disk, but when I get it using `os.getenv('NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI')`, i.e. the currently selected folder in nautilus, it appears in python as

`/media/music/k%C3%A1lm%C3%A1n balogh and the gipsy cimbalom band/aven shavale`

and then other actions such as renaming or copying the file don't work because it doesn't find the file on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at url encoding. Use [`urllib.unquote()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) to interpret these to UTF-8 encoded text, then decode to unicode:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote('/media/music/k%C3%A1lm%C3%A1n balogh and the gipsy cimbalom band/aven shavale').decode('utf8')
u'/media/music/k\xe1lm\xe1n balogh and the gipsy cimbalom band/aven shavale'
>>> print urllib.unquote('/media/music/k%C3%A1lm%C3%A1n balogh and the gipsy cimbalom band/aven shavale').decode('utf8')
/media/music/kálmán balogh and the gipsy cimbalom band/aven shavale
```

In Python 3, you need to use [`urllib.parse.unquote()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote); the function was moved.